# Will updating grub overwrite Windows Boot Manager if Ubuntu is installed on a USB stick?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I've successfully installed Ubuntu 20.04 onto a 64GB USB stick, as I only intend to use it occasionally, while having Windows 10 installed on my laptop's SSD.

I installed the Ubuntu with a desktop after unplugging the internal disks, to not mess with the desktop's original OS.

Now that I have a full installation on the USB stick, a question comes to me: 
If in the future GRUB gets an update, and I update it, will the process mess up my laptop's own Windows boot? Because I can't remove the internal SSD with Windows installed in my laptop so easily, if at the time of GRUB's update, the internal SSD is present, will the update overwrite my Windows Boot Manager and causes issue booting into Windows without the USB stick?

Answer (score 1):

I have kept a Ubuntu 12.04 installation on a USB drive for last 5 years for occasional / emergency use. Above that this USB installation grub menu shows a windows installation also which do not exit at all. When I was used to boot in to windows system without USB I used to boot without any problem. So as far as I understand you should not face any problem. If you feel any problem at any time just run boot-repair.

Answer (score 1):

### Grub on Bootable USB Vs Windows on SSD

I have been playing with Ubuntu Full install USB's for fourteen years and have never had a grub update on the USB affect the internal drive.

Doing an `update-grub` on the USB will add Windows to the grub menu of the USB as long as Windows and Ubuntu both boot the same mode, (either BIOS or UEFI).

It is therefore a good idea to install Ubuntu to the USB in the same mode Windows is installed in, generally UEFI for Win 10.